# Should we avoid overusing useRef?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) they explicitly recommend [not to overuse refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

Now that we have hooks it's very easy to create closures inside `useEffect`, having mutable values being stale between renders. I've read [this article](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) by Dan Abramov describing this problem for a specific use case, and it even has a section called [Refs to the Rescue!](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/#refs-to-the-rescue).

I know `useRef` is just wrapping our value in an object and keeping the reference to that object between renders, and in Dan's article it's not used to reference a DOM element but to keep a mutable value updated between renders.

My question is, should we avoid overusing `useRef`? If it depends on the scenario, when would it be ok and when not so much?

Comment: I'm not sure that is the 100% right place to ask such questions. I believe what they mean is "if you can come up with a solution without ref don't use ref". But I may be wrong. Try also ask [here](https://reactjs.org/community/support.html#popular-discussion-forums)